# Python utf-8 character range

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8

I work with a text file, encoded with utf-8, and read its contents with python. After reading the content, I split the text to characters array.

```
import codecs

with codecs.open(fullpath,'r',encoding='utf8') as f:
    text = f.read()
    # Split the 'text' to characters
```

Now, I'm iterating on each character. First, convert it to its hexadecimal representation and running some code on it.

```
numerialValue = ord(char)
```

I have noticed that between all those characters, some characters are beyond the expected range.

> Expected max value - FFFF. 
>   Actual character value - 1D463.

I translated this code to python. The original source code is coming from C#, whose value '\u1D463' is invalid character.

[image]

Being confused.

Comment: Python2 or Python3?

Comment: Could it be this https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord "If a unicode argument is given and Python was built with UCS2 Unicode, then the character’s code point must be in the range [0..65535] inclusive; otherwise the string length is two, and a TypeError will be raised." as 1D463 = 119907

Comment: @Sarcoma, So, if i understand it rigth, the value range should be 0000 to FFFF or TypeError with be thrown? In my case, I get value larger then FFFF instead of TypeError exception

Comment: I think that is only applicable to Python2 that has been built with UCS2 Unicode.

Comment: WHAT exactly is what confuses you??? I can't see any confusing things in what you write in your question ... (except my confusion about WHAT is what confuses YOU?)

Answer (score 3):

It seems you escaped your Unicode code-point (U+1D463) with `\u` instead of `\U`.  The former expects four hex digits, where the latter expects eight hex digits. According to Microsoft Visual Studio:

`The condition was ch == '\u1D463'`

When I used this literal in Python Interpreter, it doesn't complain but it escapes the first four hex digits happily and 3 prints normally when run in cmd:

```
 >>> print('\u1D463')
ᵆ3
```

You got this exception:`Expected max value - FFFF. Actual character value - 1D463` because you're using the incorrect unicode escape, use `\U0001D463` instead of `\u1D463`. The maximum value for characters code-points in `\u` is `\uFFFF` and the maximum value for `\U` is `\UFFFFFFFF`. Notice the leading zeros in `\U0001D463`, `\U` takes *exactly* eight hex digits and `\u` takes *exactly* four hex digits:

```
>>> '\U1D463'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-6: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

>>> '\uFF'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-3: truncated \uXXXX escape
```